# Farewell; and let your haste commend your duty

Tags: meaning, shakespeare

Here's from *Hamlet*, Act 1, Scene 2.

> and we here dispatch
>
> You, good Cornelius, and you, Voltimand,
>
> For bearers of this greeting to old Norway;
>
> Giving to you no further personal power
>
> To business with the king, more than the scope
>
> Of these dilated articles allow.
>
> Farewell; and let your haste commend your duty.

I wonder what exactly "let your haste commend your duty" means.

Comment: "hurry up, or you'll look like a slacker"

Comment: I see no reason to close this question. It's on-topic and has a definitive, easily-supported answer. (That said, if someone *does* essay to answer, I would really like to see reference made to a well-known analysis of Shakespeare, not just personal opinion.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To rephrase completely, he is saying that if they have a strong sense of duty, they should show it by departing and completing the task quickly.

The phrase is similar to the saying "let your actions speak for themselves".

[Commend](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commend) means to speak highly of, so we could rephase it as "let your haste speak highly of your duty".

In the military and often in Shakespeare, a strong sense of duty is considered important and is closely tied with the idea of honor. Honor is a common theme in many of Shakespeare's works, including *Hamlet* and *King Henry IV* [2](http://www.quilldrivers.com/honor.shtml).